# Statistical test for "too perfect" random number generator?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I am attempting to characterize some random number generator programs in a very simple way.  Specifically, I'm rolling a simulated 6-sided die $3 \times 10^8$ times and keeping a count of how many times each of the six possible outcomes happens.  I have used a $\chi^2$ test for each of the different random number generators.  That is, for all of the observation counts $O_i$ and the expected value of $E=3\times10^8/6$ I calculate: $$ \chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{(O_i-E)^2}{E}$$
This value is then compared to 20.52, which, if I've understood correctly is the correct value for $p=0.001$ and 5 degrees of freedom as in [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Table_of_.CF.872_value_vs_p-value).

All of the random number generators pass this test, but I notice that some of them look a little too good.  That is, the value of $\displaystyle \frac{(O_i-E)^2}{E}$ is less than 0.1 for each observation count.

I have looked at the fifteen [NIST random number generator tests](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/stats_tests.html) but I'd rather not run all of those tests and don't know which (if any) of those tests captures the notion I'm trying to convey.

So my questions is: **Is there a statistically valid test that expresses this notion of "too good" in this context?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_i$ be the result of die roll $i$. Note that each die face has $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of occurring, so lets focus on the statistical properties of $\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$. For a given value of $N=$ number of die rolls, let $Y^i_N=\sum\limits_{j=1}^N \mathbb{I}_{i}(D_i)$, where $\mathbb{I}_{i}(D_i)=1$ iff $D_i=i$ and is $0$ otherwise.

Therefore, $Y_N^i\sim Bin(N,\frac{1}{6})$. From the central limit theorem we know that:

$Y_N^i\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(Np_i,Np_i(1-p_i))$

From the above we can see that for a given $N$ we have  $O_i=Y_N^i$ thus $(O_i-E_i)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,Np_i(1-p_i))\implies \frac{(O_i-E_i)}{\sqrt{E_i}}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1-p_i)$

If we square this result, we can conclude that $Var\left(\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}\right)\leq Var(\chi^2_1) = 1$ and $P(\chi^2_1\leq 0.1)=25\%$ So getting any single term to be so low is not unusual.

However, if, as you say, every term is $\leq 0.1$, then $P(\chi^2_5\leq 0.5)<0.001$

Here's what you can try: Generate $N>50$ runs from each RNG you are testing, each with a different starting seed. For each run, perform your Chi-square test and look at the distribution of resulting p-values - they should look uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. If you want to be a bit more rigorous, you can perform a Komolgorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test using $H_0=$Standard Uniform distribution for each RNG's p-values to see if they are sufficiently uniform. If so, then what you saw was a statistical anomaly. If the p-values are skewed, then something weird is going on.